# Stop BLE when using WiFi

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, wifi, esp32, wifimanager, arduino-esp32

I'm trying to use BLE and WiFi on ESP32. As I've seen they can't be used at the same time, so I'm trying to figure out a way to stop receiving data from a BLE server. This are the methods to stop BLE that I have tried so far:

```
btStop();
esp_bt_controller_disable();
esp_bluedroid_disable();
```

However, none seem to work. The ESP32 supposedly connects to WiFi (using WiFiManager), but when I try to connect to Firebase or Twilio the connection is refused. Before trying to connect to Firebase I have 35000 free heap and twilio 80000. **So, is there a way to check whether the BLE scan/connection has been stopped? Are there any other commands to turn it off?** Could it be that I am running out of heap and I can't connect to Firebase because of that?

Comment: `esp_bt_controller_disable()` should do the trick. What makes you think BLE is still enabled?

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan Thanks for your reply! I think it's still enabled because I can't make a HTTP request to Firebase or Twilio. Is there a way to check whether BLE is still enabled?

Comment: Does your code that tries to talk to Firebase work if you remove the Bluetooth code altogether? I suspect Bluetooth may not be the problem.

Comment: @romkey Yes, my code works fine and successfuly pushes data to Firebase, when I'm not using BLE.

Answer (score 2):

You're currently missing a couple of deinit calls

```
esp_bluedroid_disable();
esp_bluedroid_deinit();  //**
esp_bt_controller_disable();
esp_bt_controller_deinit(); //**
```

You might also have to ensure Wi-Fi hasn't been *started* while BLE was enabled, you can *init*, but starting might cause issues where it starts trying to use the radio immediately

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the BLEDevice Library try this:

```
 BLEDevice::deinit(true);
```